# IllegalStateException [start called in an invalid state: 1] on restarting Android MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I am trying to implement simple logic to start/stop recording with `MediaRecorder` of Android.

The cycle is

1. connect to localSocket / set options / mRecorder.prepare();
2. mRecorder.start();
3. mRecorder.stop();  mRecorder.reset();

Then, loop between 2 and 3.

In the first cycle, 1,2,3 works fine as intended, however, I've got an error on the second start(restart) after the first stop.

`com.example.app E/MediaRecorder﹕ start called in an invalid state: 1`

What is the MediaRecorder `state 1`? What do I miss?
Thanks for your input.

```
if (cmd.equals("connect"))
{
    try
    {
        sender.connect(new LocalSocketAddress(SOCKET_ADDRESS)); 
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(sender.getFileDescriptor()); 
        mRecorder.prepare(); 
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {   e.printStackTrace();  } 
} 
if (cmd.equals("start"))
{
    try
    { 
        mRecorder.start(); 
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e)
    { e.printStackTrace();  } 
} 
if (cmd.equals("stop"))
{ 
    try
    {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.reset(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd had the same problem. I had to make a function `initRecorder` that sets up and prepares the media recorder. Then I called this function each time after the start button was pressed but before start was called. `recreate()` after stop also works.

```
    StartRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 100);

            try {
                try {
                    initRecorder(mHolder.getSurface());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mMediaRecorder.start();

                Log.e("mRecorder", "Started");
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("mRecorder", "Start Failure");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });


private void initRecorder(Surface surface) throws IOException {

    toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 1000);

    if (mMediaRecorder == null) mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

   // mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    //       mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(8);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    //mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
   // mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640,480);

    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path);

  // mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
    mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // 10 seconds
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        Log.e("mRecorder", "Prepared");
    } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e("mRecorder", "Prepare Failure");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mInitSuccesful = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the scond cycle you have not called prepare, you need to call that before you can call start on media recorder

Comment: Thanks, actually, I've tried that already. The result is `E/MediaRecorder﹕ setOutputFile called in an invalid state(1)`; basically same....

Comment: OOPS didnt see the state, state 1 is when media recorder is not stopped and is recording, ur calling start on recording state. can u double check u had stopped recording in first cycke

Comment: eah, I will check that. that state1 detail is informative. thanks!

Comment: I have double checked, and I think recording is stopped. In fact, I output data from the LocalSocket, and have seen the data flow is stopped, and after a while, the re-start is triggered, so it does not make sense MR is state 1.

Comment: either it does not start properly or stop properly after ur first cycle try and check the audio file produced, are u able to play it using in built players

Comment: Again, it's passed to LocalSocket stream. I have a feeling `sender.getFileDescriptor()` as the target of `setOutputFile` is still alive, so the state is `1`

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-answer, but I would not check as the answer because it's just work-around.

According to @Pulkit Sethi, `state-1` means either `MediaRecorder` does not start properly or stop properly.

Perhaps, it's due to the local socket object `sender.getFileDescriptor()` as the target of `setOutputFile`.

So far, it's way too complicated and I could not find a way to stop gracefully enough to re-start or re-use MediaRecorder, I chose to dispose all everytime.

So 
The cycle is

1. start localSocket/Server
2. connect to localSocket / set options / mRecorder.prepare();
3. mRecorder.start();
4. stop/close/release whole

This looks not the smartest way, but at least simple and stable, and I am happy with the result to start/stop/ & re-start as intended.

```
   if (cmd.equals("stop"))

    try
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            sender.close();
        }
        if (receiver != null)
        {
            receiver.close();
        }
        if (server != null)
        {
            server.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 
    sender = null;
    receiver = null;
    server = null;  
}
```

for MediaRecorder

`mRecorder.release();`

Answer (score 0):

The output file needs to be an actual file, not a socket. This is because MediaRecorder usually needs to be able to seek back in the file to update the header when the recording ends, and you can't seek in a socket.