# Failed to get the Surface while Recording screen on Android using MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, android-studio, screen-recording, mediarecorder-api

I Want to record screen of my phone. when I test it on API 23 it works fine but when i test code on api 22 it fails to get the surface, but code works well on android marshmallow.

```
private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay()
{
    return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity",
            DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, mScreenDensity,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
            mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null
            /*Handler*/);
}
```

Recieve Error on

> mMediaRecorder.getSurface()

This is the screen shot of error [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to get surface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711723/java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to-get-surface)

Comment: I read this link. it cant solve my problem . i use the same order and my application is runnind on API level 23 but gives error on device having API level 22. I also check the permission given in the manifest. its all correct.

Comment: @Muhammadwajih Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Give runtime permission.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(TestInstructions.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(TestInstructions.this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(TestInstructions.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(TestInstructions.this,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
        Snackbar.make(relativeLayout, R.string.label_permissions, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("ENABLE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(TestInstructions.this, new String[] {
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO },
                                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
                    }
                }).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(TestInstructions.this,
                new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO },
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
    }
}
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: I know permissions are the first thing that comes to mind, but this issue seems to be a bug on Marshmallow devices. For some reason `mediarecorder.getSurface()` returns null.